# How to catch char * exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to catch a char * type exception in main() but the program crashes with the following message: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    char myarray[10];
    try
    {
        for (int n=0; n<=10; n++)
        {
            if (n>9)
            throw "Out of range";
            myarray[n]='a';
        }
    }
    catch (char * str)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << str << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use const:

```
catch (const char * str)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << str << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer.  A string literal is `const`, so needs to be caught as such.   The other answers (about constructing and throwing `std::exception` or derived types) are good style, but answer a different question.

Answer (score 4):

You *don't* want to catch `char*`.

I don't know where this idea comes from that string literals are `char*`: *they're not*.

String literals are `const char[N]` which decays to `const char*`.

Catch `const char*`.

Your program is being terminated because, at present, you're actually not handling your exception!

Answer (score 3):

Prefer an exception:

```
try {
    for (int n=0; n<=10; n++) {
        if (n>9) throw std::runtime_error("Out of range");
        myarray[n]='a';
    }
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If l try to throw an int l cannot catch it either

Comment: You did not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ Standard library provides a base class specifically designed to declare objects to be thrown as exceptions. It is called std::exception and is defined in the  header. This class has a virtual member function called what that returns a null-terminated character sequence (of type char *) and that can be overwritten in derived classes to contain some sort of description of the exception.

```
// using standard exceptions
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class myexception: public exception
{
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return "My exception happened";
  }
} myex;

int main () {
  try
  {
    throw myex;
  }
  catch (exception& e)
  {
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For more help: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: You did not answer the question.

Answer (score -4):

You cannot throw a string like that, you need to create an object.

Replace `throw "Out of range"` by `throw std::out_of_range("Out of range")`

Regards,

Comment: You are mistaken. You can throw whatever you like.